# Why we need to use 'get_absolute_url()' instead of custom defined similar methods?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

Below is the method *get_absolute_url()* used in my Tag model class:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post_by_tag', args=[self.slug])
```

Below is the way I access it in my template:

```
<a href="{{ tag.get_absolute_url }}">{{ tag }}</a>
```

It works fine. However, if I changed it to  method name like *get_abs()* in both model and template files, still it works.

As I can use custom method, I just want to know if there is any specfic reason to use get_absolute_url() as the method name to get the URI. Or, is it just a convention ?

I am using Python 3.6.6 and Django 2.1.

Comment: It is not a custom method, but a custom _name_, since both do the same action.

Comment: See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url). Django e.g. uses it in the admin to link to an object's detail page in the website.

Comment: @guillermo chamorro logically it may be same but technically both are different methods right?

Comment: @Angom I think you are right since the method must be in the parent class, and you can override it.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I understand that, even I am doing the same in my app also, but my concern is, since the same functionality works even if I use different method name, then what is point of implementing it specifically. The docs could have mention to create 'a method' instead of 'get_absolute_url()' specifically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason to use the specific name `get_absolute_url` is that there is various built-in functionality in Django that will use that name if it is provided. One example is in the [generic editing class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#model-forms), where that method will be used as the destination to redirect to on successful save.

Another example is in the admin, where the ['view on site' link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.view_on_site) on an object's change page will use that method if it exists.